# How to correlate CNV with transcriptomic data?

Tags: copy-number-variation, tcga

I have a list of differentially expressed genes. I want to correlate these genes with CNVs. I have downloaded the data from both TCGA and FireBrowse. But I am not able to understand how to do the correlation? How should I analyze the CNV data. Do you have to do some processing to get a list of CNVs with a score or something to do the correlation? Please help

Comment: Might be better off moving this post to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, I'm voting to close this question because it better fits [Bioinformatics.SE], but please do **not** crosspost, instead request migration. ———— In addition, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 